# Open web browser window in VS 2010 via add-in code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, browser, c#-2.0, add-in

I'm porting a VS Add-in to VS 2010 from VS 2008 and need to be able to open the built-in web browser.

In VS 2008, it was possible to get a handle on the web browser window with code like this:

```
var win = _applicationObject.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindWebBrowser);
```

However, the same code does not work in VS 2010 when an instance of the web browser has not already been opened. Instead it gives an `ArgumentException` on the Item index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
_applicationObject.ItemOperations.Navigate("about:blank", vsNavigateOptions.vsNavigateOptionsDefault);
```

This code opens the specified file in the browse window whether it's already opened or not. And then it's possible to grab a reference to the window object and wire up events such as `BeforeNavigate2`.